# Powershell script to track login status for a website

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0, powershell-4.0

I have a URL (e.g. **[www.abc.com](http://www.abc.com)**) and after successful login it will redirect to (e.g **[www.xyz.com](http://www.xyz.com)**) and in case of login failure it will redirect to ( e.g. **[www.pqr.com](http://www.pqr.com)**)

I need to track login status using Powershell script.

I have tried below but it's always giving me success as output.

```
$url = 'www.abc.com'
$user = 'username'
$pass = 'password'

$pair = "$($user):$($pass)"
$encodedCreds = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes($pair))
$basicAuthValue = "Basic $encodedCreds"

$Headers = @{
                 Authorization = $basicAuthValue
            }
$req = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $url -Headers $Headers

    $StatusCode = [int] $req.StatusCode;
    $StatusDescription = $req.StatusDescription;

    write-host $req
    write-host $StatusCode
    write-host $StatusDescription
```

Comment: What exactly do you expect? If a successful login successfully redirects to xyz and a not successful login successfully redirects to pqr, then of course all cases return success. If you need a login status in your script, evaluate `$req` where it has been successfully redirected. Then you know, if the login was successful or not.

Comment: Hi @Thomas , every time i am getting same content withing $req irrespective of wrong username/correct username , so not able to check whether it was successful login or not?

Comment: So you always get redirected to xyz.com?

Comment: @Thomas, write-host $req always giving me conetent of abc.com only with status code as OK, Am i missing something here?

Comment: my website is SSO, so i think it's not working with Basic credentials.

Comment: If it is SSO with your Windows, add `-UseDefaultCredentials` to your `Invoke-WebRequest`. And also pass `-SessionVariable MySession` to it. Use `-WebSession $MySession` on every following request.

Answer (score 0):

You can manipulate internet explorer with PowerShell.

Let's say you create the object for it

```
$objIE = New-Object -ComObject InternetExplorer.Application
```

Navigate to the URL

```
$objIE.Navigate($SomeURL)
```

You can then find the login buttons with the various available methods for locating elements, it could be class, Id, all sorts of stuff.

```
$SearchButton = $objIE.Document.getElementById('SomeElementId')
```

You can input text in the fields and click the button but I'm not going to make this comment into a full-on tutorial.
When you get redirected simply do `$ObjIE.LocationURL` to get the current URL.

I know this uses a different implementation than what you have provided but that's the way I know about.

Comment: Hi, 
My signIn button is having below HTML so i am not able find any name/id tag to click on it.


<span class="signin" tabIndex="3"><span class="loginInner">Sign in</span></span>

Comment: @Ganesh you can use getElementByClassName('loginInner')

Comment: Thanks @orel, i already tried below coomand: $link=$ie.Document.getElementsByClassName('loginInner')
 $link.item().click()

but got below error:
Error: +  $link=$ie.Document.getElementsByClassName('loginInner')
+  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : OperationStopped: (:) [], NotSupportedException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.NotSupportedException
 
The RPC server is unavailable. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x800706BA)

Comment: Is it possible to use Invoke-WebRequest to get login status?

Comment: You used GetElements, which returns an array, use GetElement which will only return the first occurance for which loginInner is the class :) Also, you can just do $link.Click() (Assuming it's a button)\